# Check in cell (in TextView) text or link (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview

I have a table with **ImageView** and **TextView**

How can i check if in cell i have **text** then (in image view = Image "Text"), else if in cell i have **link** (in image view = Image "Link")

```
var myData: [String] = []

func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {
    if (URL.scheme?.contains("http"))! || (URL.scheme?.contains("https"))! {
        cell.ImageV?.image = UIImage(named:"Link")
        print("Link")
    } else {
        cell.ImageV?.image = UIImage(named:"Text")
        print("Text")
    }
    return false
}
```

**Example:**
[image]

**But it not work**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    cell.nameText?.text = myData[indexPath.row]
    //
    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {
        if (URL.scheme?.contains("http"))! || (URL.scheme?.contains("https"))! {
            // Handle links
            cell.ImageV?.image = UIImage(named:"Link")
            print("Link")
        } else {
            // Handle anything else that has slipped through.
            cell.ImageV?.image = UIImage(named:"Text")
            print("Text")
        }
        return false
    }
    return cell
}
```

**Save and Load:**

```
func save() {
  UserDefaults.standard.set(myData, forKey: "notes")
  //UserDefaults.standard.set(Data, forKey: "ImageDate")
  UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
}
//
func load(){
    if let loadData = UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: "notes") {
        myData = loadData

        table.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify your question? What's your goal?

Comment: @Larme I have an application type of notes

I need that when I create a record in a table with a link, then the picture in cell would be with a link (Image "Link"), and if I created an entry in the table with the text, then the picture in cell would be with the text (Image "Text")

Comment: @B2Fq did you try to put your code in tableView: cellForRow method ?

Comment: @ArthurSahakyan Yes

Comment: @B2Fq then please post more code, and say what is your question here, what is not working ? Help us to help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATED**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell     
{
     let dict = myData[indexPath.row]

     if dict.contains("http") || dict.contains("https")
     {
          print("Link")
     }
     else{
          print("Text")
     }
}
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Error - Cannot subscript a value of type 'String' with an index of type 'String'

Comment: it is empty I know - var myData: [String] = []

Comment: I save my notes in UserDefaults

Comment: Okay can you please show me your myData. I mean what is in i want to show data

Comment: How do I save them?

Comment: Save and Load in question

Comment: Great happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You can check if text is URL or not with following code

```
guard let url = URL(string: self.text!) else { return false }
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
    // url
}else {
    //not an url
}
```